# ¿Como conectarse a sql anywhere 9 sybase desde android?

Tags: android, sybase

Tengo una base de datos en sql anywhere 9.0 y la trabajo mediante sybase, tengo una aplicacion de escritorio en POWER BUILDER que ingresa productos, los cuales quiero mostrarlos en una aplicacion hecha en android studio, solo debo mostrar una lista de esos productos en mi proyecto de android, para lo cual he probado conectarme mediante jdbc. En Power builder, utilizo el odbc para conectarme, pero se que android utiliza jdbc, quisiera conectarme a esa base de datos para obtener los datos, he probado lo siguiente:
`Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConectionURL="jdbc:jtds:odbc:driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0};ENG=ARCHIVO;UID=" + us + ";PWD="+ pass + ";DBN="+bd + ";LINK=TCPIP(HOST="+ip+":2638)";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConectionURL);`
el jtds es una libreria descargada de internet que permite conexiones con sql server, la descargue y la probe en mi aplicación pero no se si sea la forma correcta de implementarla, alguien me puede ayudar diciendome como poner la url y la clase?
A continuacion les pongo el codigo completo de mi conexion.

```
    package com.example.systemsecpc3.aplicacionsystemsproductos.connections;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Systems Ec pc3 on 16/12/2017.
 */

public class Conexion {


    //declaramos las variables de conexion
    Connection con = null;
    public String ip, bd, us, pass;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Conexion(String usuariobd, String clavebd, String BaseDatos, String ServerIp){
        us=usuariobd;
        bd=BaseDatos;
        pass=clavebd;
        ip=ServerIp;

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String ConectionURL =null;

        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConectionURL="jdbc:jtds:odbc:driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0};ENG=ARCHIVO;UID=" + us + ";PWD="+ pass + ";DBN="+bd + ";LINK=TCPIP(HOST="+ip+":2638)";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConectionURL);

        }catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("Error SQL 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException  e)
        {
            Log.e("Error Class 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error Exception 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }

    }


    public Connection getConnection(){
        return con;
    }
    public void desconectar(){
        con = null;
    }
}


y este es el codigo de mi mainactivity

    package com.example.systemsecpc3.aplicacionsystemsproductos.activities;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.systemsecpc3.aplicacionsystemsproductos.R;
import com.example.systemsecpc3.aplicacionsystemsproductos.connections.Conexion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declaramos elementos del layout
    Button probar;
    TextView texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //obtenemos en la variable los elementos del layout
        probar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        probar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Conexion cc=new Conexion("dba","sql", "SYSTEMS","192.168.1.126");
                Connection cn= cc.getConnection();
                Statement st=null;
                ResultSet rs;
                try {
                    st=(Statement) cn.createStatement();
                    rs=st.executeQuery("select max(*) from bo_producto");
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        texto.setText(rs.getString("ENCTONTRÓ DATOS"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        texto.setText(rs.getString("NO ENCONTRÓ DATOS"));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Log.e("Error here 1 : ", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: ok gracias por la indicacion